# How come static variable is usable even before it is declared in C#

Tags: c#, static-variables

I'm able to compile and run the following program successfully:

```
class MyClass1
{
    public static int x = y;
    public static int y = 10;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyClass1.x); //prints 0
    Console.WriteLine(MyClass1.y); //prints 10
}
```

Why it is compiling successfully? How does `x` gets the value of `y` even before it is declared and initialized? The same gets compile time error had it been the case of instance fields.

Comment: Define "before". Since they're static MyClass1 doesn't need to be instantiated to use x and y, so "before" in this case would only be before you added them to the class.

Comment: Couldn't quite follow you. I know that both x and y are static fields. Initialization happens for static fields through static constructor when we try to access any static field or static method for the first time (x in this case) for a type. When it happens I believe y should be available when x is getting initialized but y is found on next line which is problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ECMA-334 - 17.4.5.1 Static field initialization

> The static field variable initializers of a class declaration
>   correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the
>   textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. If a
>   static constructor (§17.11) exists in the class, execution of the
>   static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that
>   static constructor. **Otherwise, the static field initializers are
>   executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of
>   a static field of that class**.

So `y` variable is used in the line of initialization of `x` variable and get initialized with default value which is `0`

Answer (score 0):

They are initialized in order. First `x` is set to the value of `y`, which is 0 (the default). Then `y` is set to 10.